# Search for php function in text

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm building a template class and i want to fetch the text of the template to seek php code. I want to seek for a custom function named "_l" because i want to add an extra param when it get parsed. An example
If i have a template like this:

```
Hi there! <?=_l('Hello')?> World
```

It must become something like this:

```
Hi there! <?=_l('Hello', 'Other Param')?> World
```

U've the necessity to find the function and to modify it dynamically, i can't use grep and i can't edit the _l function. I've to this because every function have to get a different parameter. And the result will get cached to avoid system overload! I just need a system to it on live! :)

What is the better solution?
Ah, sorry for bad english!

Thanks

Comment: Why not just change the existing `_l` function?

Comment: the best solution? grep it, or use a texteditor with regexp find/replace functionality...

Comment: I've the necessity to find the function and to modify it dynamically, i can't use grep and i can't edit the _l function. I've to this because every function have to get a different parameter. And the result will get cached to avoid system overload! I just need a system to it on live! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `preg_replace()` with regex:

```
$str = "Hi there! <?=_l('Hello')?> World";
$str = preg_replace("/(<\?=_l\(')([^']*')\)/", "$1$2, 'Other Param')", $str);
```

`<?=_l('` is picked in group-1 `$1` and `Hello'` is picked in group-2 `$2`. Then added additional `'Other Param')` at the end of replacement.

Comment: But using this expression i have to write it exactly like this. I need to check on a code like this too: Test test <?php some php code... echo _l('Here') .. other php code ... ?>

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\b(_l\('[^']*')\)/s", "$1, 'Other Param')", $string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way! :)

```
$txt = preg_replace_callback("/\<\?(php|\=)(.+?)\?\>/is", function( $m ){
    while(preg_match("/\b(_l\(.+?)\)/is", $m[2])){
        $m[2] = preg_replace_callback("/\b_l\((.+?)\)/is", function($matches){
            return "_le({$matches[1]}, 'other'}";
        }, $m[2] );
    }

    $m[2] = str_replace("'other'}", "'other')", $m[2]);

    return $m[1]=='='?"<?php echo {$m[2]} ?>":"<?php {$m[2]} ?>";
}, $txt );
```